# C# Deserialize JSON to a lower level?

Tags: c#

I am deserializing some JSON into a list of the type Data1.

**The class:**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Data1> data { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int requested { get; set; }
    public int performed { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    public List<ClioFolder> data { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}

public class ClioFolder
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Parent parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**The Json:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 66880231,
          "name": "root",
          "parent": null
        },
        {
          "id": 68102146,
          "name": "Dummy",
          "parent": {
            "id": 66880231,
            "name": "root"
          }
        }
      ],
      "status": 200
    }
  ],
  "status": "completed",
  "requested": 10,
  "performed": 10
}
```

Using this command:

```
List<Data1> allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content).data;
```

This is working fine, but what I really need is the data from within the two "data" objects in it's own list too. I thought I would be able to do something like:

```
List<ClioFolder> allClios = allData.data;
```

But this doesn't work. I did also try deserailizing from the JSON directly into this second list, but this doesn't work either:

```
List<Cliofolder> allClios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content).data.data;
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by. `doesn't work`?

Comment: You should do `List<ClioFolder> allClios = allData[0].data;`

Comment: I have to say, I thought I tried everything, including what you mentioned but I had somehow missed that. It's working. Thanks. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a list. your should use:

```
List<ClioFolder> test = allData.FirstOrDefault()?.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

tried to make a clean example. and im pretty sure this can be achieved with linq but i can't think of how to flatten a multidimensional array in linq right now.

```
List<ClioFolder> allClios = new List<ClioFolder>();    

foreach(Data1 data in allData)
{
    allClios.AddRange(data.data.ToArray());

}
```